# How to retrieve specific data from Parse Cloud Service

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to get a user's stored name from Parse using the following code:

```
ParseUser puParseUser = ParseUserProfile.getCurrentUser();
String sParseUserObjectID = puParseUser.getObjectId();
ParseQuery<ParseUserProfile> pqUserProfileQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseUserProfile.class);
                    pqUserProfileQuery.getInBackground(sParseUserObjectID, new GetCallback<ParseUserProfile>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
              sFirstName = object.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.keyParseFirstName));
              sMiddleName = object.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.keyParseMiddleName));
              sSurname = object.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.keyParseSurname));

              if (sFirstName == null) {
                   Log.e(KEAMapActivity.this.toString(), "ParseUser FirstName is NULL: " + sFirstName);  //  TODO: For Testing ONLY

                   txtDrawerHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sWelcome));
              } else if (sMiddleName == null) {
                   Log.e(KEAMapActivity.this.toString(), "ParseUser MiddleName is NULL: " + sMiddleName);  //  TODO: For Testing ONLY

                   txtDrawerHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sWelcome));
              } else if (sSurname == null) {
                   Log.e(KEAMapActivity.this.toString(), "ParseUser Surname is NULL: " + sSurname);  //  TODO: For Testing ONLY

                   txtDrawerHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sWelcome));
              } else {
                   Log.e(KEAMapActivity.this.toString(), "ParseUser Name is: " + sFirstName + sMiddleName + sSurname);  //  TODO: For Testing ONLY

                   sMiddleName = sMiddleName.substring(0, 1) + ".";
                   sFullName = sFirstName + " " + sMiddleName + " " + sSurname;
                   txtDrawerHeader.setText(sFullName);
              }
        } else {
              if (e.getCode() == ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
                   Log.e(KEAMapActivity.this.toString(), "ParseUser OBJECT NOT FOUND");  //  TODO: For Testing ONLY

              txtDrawerHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sWelcome));

              } else {
                   Log.e(KEAMapActivity.this.toString(), "Error retrieving User's Name: " + e.getMessage());    //  TODO: For testing ONLY.
              }

              txtDrawerHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sWelcome));
       }
    }
});
```

The above code returns: `OBJECT_NOT_FOUND` exception. But in my own conscience, I know a parse object with the same `objectId` I provide in this code exists and it's a user object containing user data. I want to get the user's first, middle and last name.
Please note `ParseUserProfile` is a subclass of `com.parse.ParseUser` class.

What can I do to solve this? If you need more detail or have any question regarding my code, please ask.

Comment: How are you querying the user? I don't see you providing any ObjectId?

Comment: @Loolooii thanks, let me add that piece of code right now.

Comment: Print clsParseUser to see if it has an objectId. Because I don't see anywhere that that user contains any data.

Comment: More specifically: clsParseUser.getObjectId()

Comment: @Loolooii I've ensured the existence of the object id. And in this case, the objectI is: HF**U4****. ObjectId is not `null`

Comment: You are sure you're not printing puParseUser.getObjectId(); instead of clsParseUser.getObjectId()? Because you are querying the second one.

Comment: @Loolooii I've edited the source code just a little bit, so you cold see where I get `puParseUser`. It from a `com.parse.ParseUser` subclass called `ParseUserProfile`.

Comment: Do read docs, its a very helpful documentation https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries

Comment: @DineshSunny I've gone through the guide, and that's why I finally decided to ask this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your current code. Have you registered your subclass in your Application class?

Comment: @Loolooii Yes I have within the Application class with this line: `ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseUserProfile.class);`